# How to filter an item in a database by different fields in python?

Tags: python, database, filter, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am creating an application with FastAPI and I want to filter 'items' in an endpoint according to their name and category. However, I want that if any of these two fields is not passed, it is not taken into account, and if both are passed, both filters are applied.
I have written the following code for this:

```
async def filter_items_by_name_category(
        self,
        name: str | None = None,
        category: str | None = None
    ):
        if name is not None:
            items_by_name = await self.model.filter(name__icontains = name).all()
            if category is None:
                return items_by_name

        if category is not None:
            items_by_category = await self.model.filter(category = category).all()
            if name is None:
                return items_by_category

        items = [item for item in items_by_name if item in items_by_category]
        return items
```

The code works but it seems very inelegant to me! I was thinking that maybe there is another better implementation. I am using tortoise orm but I think it will not have relevance in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to dynamically generate the [Q object](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html?highlight=join_type#q-objects) that you need.

Something like:

```py
async def filter_items_by_name_category(
        self,
        name: str | None = None,
        category: str | None = None
    ):
        qs = []

        if name is not None:
            qs.append(Q(name__icontains = name)

        if category is not None:
            qs.append(category = category)

        return await self.model.filter(Q(*qs, join_type="AND")).all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really like this implementation! I knew there were better ways to do it!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the example given by Patrick Wang, [the returned query set objects](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html) can be further expanded with filters, so you can keep on extending the query for each part:

```py
query = self.model

if name is not None:
    query = query.filter(name__icontains = name)

if category is not None:
    query = query.filter(category = category)

return await query.all()
```

Comment: Incredible! I did not know that! Thank you very much for sharing it, I will use it in my day to day.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
async def filter_items_by_name_category(
        self,
        name: str = "",
        category: str = ""
    ):

    items_by_name = []
    items_by_category = []

        if name:
            items_by_name = await self.model.filter(name__icontains = name).all()
            if not category:
                return items_by_name

        if category:
            items_by_category = await self.model.filter(category = category).all()
            if not name:
                return items_by_category

        return [item for item in items_by_name if item in items_by_category]
```

Tidied a bit by using [truthy/falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) values (which avoids `None` as a default) and returning `items` instead of setting as a variable and then returning it.

Also set default empty values so the function will return `[]` if neither `name` nor `category` gets set.

I would also suggest breaking each filter into its own function, so that you can test and reuse each one independently.